# import fails when running in different environments

Tags: python

I'm using a pip.
directory structure:

```
scenario
   scenario
     parser
       __init__.py
   __init__.py
   runner.py
```

parent init

```
__all__ = ['run_scenario', 'parse_scenario_json', 'play_scenario']

from scenario.runner import run_scenario
from scenario.parser import parse_scenario_json
from scenario.player import play_scenario
```

in `runner.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from scenario.parser import parse_scenario_json
```

running from pycharm 
    [![enter image description here][1]][1]

works.

running from the terminal getting

```
(scenario) /Volumes/Development/scenario (master) python2 scenario/__main__.py -v5 -t 10.0 -f html ../04-04.out ~/Downloads/01-calc-grades-average11.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scenario/__main__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scenario.runner import run_scenario
  File "/Users/ohadperry/.virtualenvs/scenario/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scenario/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scenario.runner import run_scenario
  File "/Users/ohadperry/.virtualenvs/scenario/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scenario/runner.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scenario.parser import parse_scenario_json
ImportError: No module named parse
```

both are running from the same `virtualenv` and the same python version `2.7.13`

Since this is a pip, I even tried to run in using the installed pip

```
pip install git+https://github.com/shlomihod/scenario.git --upgrade
scenario -v5 -t 10.0 -f html ../../CEC-INGInious-Courses/07-2-C_Programming_2-TEMPLATE/PTBS/04-04.out ~/Downloads/01-calc-grades-average11.json
```

getting this output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ohadperry/.virtualenvs/scenario/bin/scenario", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('scenario==2.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'scenario')()
  File "/Users/ohadperry/.virtualenvs/scenario/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 474, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/Users/ohadperry/.virtualenvs/scenario/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2582, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/Users/ohadperry/.virtualenvs/scenario/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2265, in load
    return self._load()
  File "/Users/ohadperry/.virtualenvs/scenario/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2268, in _load
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/Users/ohadperry/.virtualenvs/scenario/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scenario/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scenario.runner import run_scenario
  File "/Users/ohadperry/.virtualenvs/scenario/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scenario/runner.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scenario.parser import parse_scenario_json
ImportError: No module named parser
```

how do you debug this?

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPAbo.png
```

Comment: use `from scenario.scenario.runner import run_scenario`

Comment: tried, didn't work. I think the problem is with the `__init__`

Comment: Rename parent directory ...

Comment: tried that as well. didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was the setup package file

```
  packages=['scenario',
            'scenario.player',
            'scenario.parser',
            'scenario.tests'],
```

added the missing packagges there

Answer (score 1):

It can be the version of the Python and the version of the lib. If you install the lib using pip you should have to use python 2.7, but if you have installed the library using pip3 you must have to use python 3.

Check the versions! This situation already happened to me.

Comment: I don't think it's related to the library version. I'm running the code before installing the pip. I'm running the code from the same virtualenv in pycharm as well as from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to make python package and installing it then package directory structure should be like this

```
funniest/
    funniest/
        __init__.py
        module1.py
        module2.py
        module3.py 
    setup.py
```

As you can see parent funniest directory is the only simple directory, not a python package.And child funniest directory is Python package.

**Note** : To define a directory as Python package define **init**.py in directory

for detail in **[python package](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html#creating-the-scaffolding)**

When you define a directory to a Python package then you can import all module defined inside the python directory in another python modules

**purpose of  __all_**

## case 1

__all_ define in the module

> when you define **__all_** in any Python module then you can import
>   only defined function, variable or classes in **__all_**

Example:  in module a.py

```
__all__ = ['var1','method1']

var1 = 10
var2 = 20

def method1():
    pass

def temp1():
    pass
```

When you import a.py in another module, you can import only **var1** or **method1**, you cant import **var2**  or **temp1**

Because you do not define in **__all_** list

```
from a import *

print var1    # run without error

method1()     # run without error 

print var2    # show error

temp1()       # show error
```

## case 2

define **all_ in __init**.py of python package

If you define __all_ in __init_.py of Python package then you can import only that modules or modules variable that defines in __all_ list

From above define directory structure

In  chield funniest __init_.py

```
__all__ = ['module1', 'module2']
```

Now you can import module1 and module2 from funniest Python package and if you try to import module3 it will show error.

[For more detail __all_ in package](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package)

In

## your case

you define __all_ in __init_.py

```
__all__ = ['run_scenario', 'parse_scenario_json', 'play_scenario']
```

Now you can import only run_scenario, parse_scenario_json play_scenario

if you try to import another module  or modules variable .function it show error

useful link:

1. [Link_1](http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html)
2. [Link_2](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html#packages)